# How to access child components in a template in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I feel like I'm having a common question but I simply don't find the right terms to search for.

I want to create a list component containing n items I can use like this:

```
<list>
  <item1></item1>
  <item2></item2>
  ...
</list>
```

But I also want to add a `control-panel` component, so the end result would be this:

```
<list>
  <item1></item1>
  <item2></item2>
  ...
  <control-panel></control-panel>
</list>
```

Obviously I don't want to add the control panel to all the usages of my `<list>` but only once to its template.

I would imagine the `<list>`-component's template to look like something like this:

```
{{children}}
<control-panel></control-panel>
```

How can I access the list's children in its template?

Comment: did you take a look at [view child](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/viewchild) and view Children in Angular

Comment: @RahulSingh I had a look on it before, yes. But `<ng-content>` was the thing I was looking for, and that wasn't mentioned in previous sources I found. I thought it would be something very simple though. Thank you!

Comment: glad that helped